# php - cant scrape the pages with meta tag as noindex,nofollw

Tags: php, curl, simple-html-dom

Recently I tried to scrape a website using curl and i got nothing in browser. I found it returning the header with

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">
```

and the code i used to scrape is

```
function readThisPage($url){



            $curlHeaders = array (
                    'Accept-Language: en-us',
                    'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.15) Gecko/20110303 Firefox/3.6.15',
                    'Connection: Keep-Alive',

            );
            $context = stream_context_create (array ('http' => array ('timeout' => 60)));
            $ch = curl_init($url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $curlHeaders);


            $buffer = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);


            return $buffer;


        }
```

also i tried with `file_get_html()` both returns the same. How can I scrape these kind of websites.

Comment: Maybe start with `curl_getinfo($ch)` to get some information?